# Check whether values are in sequentially numbered variables using SQL

Tags: sql, sas

I would like to check whether any of `k` values that are strings appear in any of `n` sequentially numbered variables in a table in an elegant way. I am using `proc sql` in `SAS`.

Suppose `k=3` and `n=10`. My current solution is as follows:

```
proc sql;
create table my_filtered_data as
    SELECT *
    FROM   my_dsn. table_on_T_SQL_server
    WHERE  sequential_variable_1 in ('value 1', 'value 2', 'value 3')
           OR
           sequential_variable_2 in ('value 1', 'value 2', 'value 3')
           OR
           sequential_variable_3 in ('value 1', 'value 2', 'value 3')
           OR
           sequential_variable_4 in ('value 1', 'value 2', 'value 3')
           OR
           ...
           OR
           sequential_variable_10 in ('value 1', 'value 2', 'value 3')
           ;
quit;
```

Where `value 1`, `value 2` and `value 3` are character strings.

This is a hard coded solution that will not scale well.

Is there a more elegant way to solve this?

Comment: Why not just normalize the data so there is only ONE variable to test?

Comment: @Tom, the data are strings, not numeric. I will edit my question to convey this.

Comment: Variable type does not matter. It is the dataset structure that is sub-optimal.  If you have N observations instead of N variables the coding is much easier.

Comment: If the two lists were in two tables then an `intersect` would tell you the answer. I don't know if SAS has something like this.

Comment: Is there any reason why you need to use SQL for this?  Why not use normal SAS code.  Then you could just create an array to reference your N variables and just loop over the array.

Comment: @Tom The 'FROM' line actually beings the data into SAS from a secure server which accepts T-SQL calls. This is the way that the data structure has been set up on the SQL server. I am not reading from file. I will update the question to reflect this. I don't want to select just the variables columns without filtering and then run a loop on an array in SAS, because this would bring in a large table into SAS for post filtering with a loop over an array.

Comment: Sounds like you need help with T-SQL syntax, not SAS syntax.

Comment: Your code shows a standard proc sql, if it's using pass through the code would be different, so a data step should work just as well.

Comment: @Reeza could you provide a solution (with code) to expand on your explanation please?

Comment: Can you provide sample data for testing?

Comment: @Reeza I don't this isn't possible because I connect using login credentials to a secure server, so I have to keep things somewhat abstract.

Comment: You can make fake data

Comment: @Reeza Is it not possible to use the fake data that's posted as part of the question?

Comment: I see code, no data....

Comment: @Reeza Aren't the made up variable names posted in the code sufficient? The made up variable names are based on the structure of the date.

Comment: Are you just want a loop to generate sql statements? Try a do loop in macro code.

Comment: The elegant way to do this is to restructure your data so that the data is more usable. Beyond that you can automate the creation of your WHERE statements otherwise using a macro instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use control data and macro code to create the where clause criteria.  The plain SQL generated will be passed implicitly by the library engine to the SQL server side for more performant operation

Example:

```
data values;
length value $50;
input value $char50.;
datalines;
value 1
value 2
value 3
;

proc sql noprint;  
  select quote(trim(value),"'")
  into :values_list separated by ','
  from values;
quit;

%put NOTE: values_list=%superq(values_list);

%macro where_clause(basename=, n=);
  %local i ;

  %do i = 1 %to &n;
  or &basename.&i in ( &values_list )
  %end;
%mend;

options mprint nosymbolgen;

proc sql noexec;
  create table want as
  select *
  from remote.results_table
  where 0
  %where_clause(basename=x_,n=20,values=work.values)
  ;
quit;
```

Comment: Your macro is not using the VALUES= parameter.

Comment: Will correct.  Artifact from earlier try that used DOSUBL in the macro, couldn't quite work it out.

Answer (score 1):

Unless T-SQL has some non-standard extension to SQL to handle this you will just have to use code generation.

If the list of values is in a dataset you could use a data step to generate the code.

So if you have a dataset named VALUES with a variable named VALUE then you could generate your example CREATE statement like this:

```
filename code temp;
data _null_;
   file code ;
   put 
 'create table my_filtered_data as'
/' select *'
/' from my_dsn.table_on_T_SQL_server'
/' where '
   ;
   do suffix=1 to 10;
     if suffix > 1 then put 'or ' @;
     put 'sequential_var_' suffix 'in (' @;
     do point=1 to nobs;
       set values point=point nobs=nobs;
       put value :$quote. @;
     end;
     put ')';
   end;
   put ';';
   stop;
run;
```

Which you could then execute using %INCLUDE statement.

```
proc sql;
%include code / source2;
quit;
```

So here is what the SAS log generated by the %INCLUDE might look like:

```
52  +create table my_filtered_data as
53  + select *
54  + from my_dsn.table_on_T_SQL_server
55  + where
56  +sequential_var_1 in ("value1" "value2" "value3" )
57  +or sequential_var_2 in ("value1" "value2" "value3" )
58  +or sequential_var_3 in ("value1" "value2" "value3" )
59  +or sequential_var_4 in ("value1" "value2" "value3" )
60  +or sequential_var_5 in ("value1" "value2" "value3" )
61  +or sequential_var_6 in ("value1" "value2" "value3" )
62  +or sequential_var_7 in ("value1" "value2" "value3" )
63  +or sequential_var_8 in ("value1" "value2" "value3" )
64  +or sequential_var_9 in ("value1" "value2" "value3" )
65  +or sequential_var_10 in ("value1" "value2" "value3" )
66  +;
```

If you need to worry about generating T-SQL compatible syntax then you might need change it to use single quotes around the values and add commas instead of spaces between the values.